# sqlite3_step failure: NOT NULL constraint failed

Tags: android, sqlite, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic 1. I have tested my app in browser and it works fine. I have used sqlite. I have a form. When I left one text input field empty the data is added to the database table. That's exactly what I want. But, it does not work in device. Whenever I left one field empty it shows the below error:

```
Object {message: "sqlite3_step failure: NOT NULL constraint failed: items.barcode", code: 6}
```

Here's my code snippet:

```
if ($scope.item.itemname && $scope.item.soldby && $scope.item.price) {
                        var query = "INSERT into items (itemname,category,soldby,price,sku,barcode) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)";

                        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [$scope.item.itemname, $scope.item.category, $scope.item.soldby, $scope.item.price, $scope.item.sku, $scope.item.barcode,])
                            .then(function (result) {
                                console.log($scope.item.itemname);
                                console.log($scope.item.category);
                                console.log($scope.item.soldby);
                                console.log($scope.item.price);
                                console.log($scope.item.sku);
                                console.log("Printing barcode");
                                console.log($scope.item.barcode);
                                console.log($scope.item.total);

                                //ITEM ADDED SUCCESS POPUP STARTS                




                                //ITEM ADDED SUCCESS POPUP ENDS  


                            }, function (error) {
                                console.log(error);

                            });

                        // $scope.item = {
                        //     itemname: $scope.item.itemname,
                        // };
                        $state.go('menu.allItems');
                    }
```

And here is the code where I created the table:

```
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS items (id integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT,itemname text ,category text ,soldby text ,price REAL ,quantity REAL ,sku integer ,barcode text,timestamp DATE DEFAULT (datetime('now','localtime')),cashier text,total REAL,receitnumber integer,grandtotal REAL)");
```

Comment: Did you ever have a previous version of the table with a NOT NULL constraint on the `barcode` column?

Comment: yes, I did have.

Comment: What to do then?? @CL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` does not change anything if a table with the same name already exists, even if it has a different structure.

To ensure that you always get rid of the old table, use:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS items;
CREATE TABLE items ( [...] );
```

This also deletes all old data. If you want to update the table definition but keep the old data, you have to [use a temporary table to do the conversion](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q11).

Comment: Is there any other way?? Because my app requires to keep the old data. What if I run drop table whenever I am making a change in the table structure and then delete the "drop table"?

Comment: Also, I want to know that why does my app works fine on browser but not i device or emulator.

Comment: The link shows how to change the table. The app doesn't work when there is an old database.

Comment: @SoumyaRauth "_why does my app works fine on browser_" a complete guess: the browser did not have a "previous instance" of the database (together with the old NOT NULL constraint) so created a new table (without the constraint). The device _did_ have a previous instance complete with the (unwanted) constraint.